# webpack You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am using webpack,while running webpack I am getting following error

Module parse failed: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0 while parsing near 'module.exports = "{...'
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/text-loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0 while parsing near 'module.exports = "{...'

here is my webpack.config.js

```
alias: {

            source : path.resolve(__dirname,"../src/")
        },
        extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".json",".css"]
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        modules: ["node_modules", path.resolve(__dirname, "./loaders/")],
        alias: {
          ojL10n: "ojL10n-loader",
          text: "text-loader",
          load : "json-loader",
          css:"css-loader"
        },
        extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".json",".css"]
    },
module: {
        rules: [
            {
            test: /\.js$/,
            include: /js/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)|(dest)/,
            use: [{
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        ]
        }
    ]
    }
```

I am not getting why its throwing error in node_modules/text-loader/index.js
and index.js is js file but in error its shows : Module parse failed: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0 while parsing near 'module.exports = "{...'

Comment: Can you share a codesandbox? that would help us to figure out the reason for the error and fix it.

Comment: is this your complete webpack conifg?